# OneDrive device management for user folder

Tags: onedrive

I'm trying to understand how OneDrive works for multiple device management. 
I want to sync my user folders on OneDrive but this files must be handled 
separately by device, not on a single cloud folder.

Google Drive has one big cloud folder but manages devices files separatedly as seen in GDrive sidebar.

[image]

Meanwhile, OneDrive has an option to save User files, but it seems that this files stays on the shared folder. It means that if some program save a setting, or saved game in a Computer A and the same program save a different file (with the same name) on Computer B they would be mixed or overwritten.

Is there avoid this behaviour?

---

### inb4:

- The `Auto save` tab on OneDrive settings lets user choose to save folder on OneDrive folder, not on a *device folder*
- There is an option to `fecth any file of device`. But PC needs to be turned on to work.

Comment: In OneDrive, there is no page to directly list all devices. In this article: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/OneDrive-for-Business/Learn-How-OneDrive-Sync-Works-With-Office-2016/td-p/41435

Comment: It indicates: If Office 2016 is not installed, OneDrive will create a second file with the user’s conflicting copy after detecting a conflict. If Office 2016 is installed, users have the option to “Open in Office” to resolve the conflict. This will either automatically merge the conflicting copies or show a merge experience that lets users pick the right version of each conflicting change. Users can choose to duplicate the file instead, or they can disable the “Open in Office” option entirely in the OneDrive settings.

Comment: @WinniL that's frustrating considering OneDrive is the native Windows cloud sync.